# How to limit max pager item count in p:dataTable or p:dataGrid?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, paginator

I would like to limit maximum pager item of [p:dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) or [p:dataGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml). I think default is **10**. I need to set it maximum of **5** pager item. Can it be possible ?

Below is my pagertemplate code.

```
        <p:dataGrid styleClass="bodyContent"
            var="item"  value="#{list}" 
            paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" 
            rows="5" lazy="true" columns="1" layout="grid" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,30,60"
            rowIndexVar="index">
```

And below is screenshoot.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pageLinks` attribute to change this. In your case:

```
<p:dataGrid ... pageLinks="5">
```

Comment: cool, did not know that and assumed the OP to have done some basic investigation (look at the documentation). And again, assumption is the mother of all <beep> ups

Comment: EXACTLY ! ..... This is my answer. I googled for a long times for this problem but I didn't found. Thank you.